# nativescript iOS build failed

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-cli

This is the xcode error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpzuQ.png)

I used a basic project (no modifications): tns create IosTest  --template tns-template-tab-navigation-ng

followed these steps:

1. tns resources generate icons
   App_Resources/iOS/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/icon-1024.png
2. tns platform add ios
3. tns build ios
4. opened xcode and set up the release for signing

then the build worked, then the archive worked,
and that error shows up when validating the archive.

I'm using nativescript version 4.2.0, and Xcode 9.2 (running on mac 10.12.6)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you have any logs?

Comment: No logs...just that screenshot at the end of validating.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the project in XCode, if there are warning signs on most of the icons, try dragging and dropping the icon from finder window into `Resources -> Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon`

Then try to build and publish from Xcode